# RTSP трансляция на android

Tags: java, android, videoview, android-view

Мне надо организовать трансляцию видео на *Android* с помощью протокола *RTSP* (в соседней комнате стоит камера, подключенная к роутеру, и транслирует видео:
 `rtsp://192.168.1.21:8557/Onvif/Streaming/2?videoCodecType=H.264`).

Обычный *VideoView* не хочет транслировать это видео (говорит, что данный формат не поддерживается). Скорее всего проблема в расширении *h264*.

На компьютере трансляцию сделать несложно с помощью *JavaCV*. Думал и на телефоне так сделать, но понятия не имею, как *Frame* переводить в *bitmap* (посредством *ByteBuffer* — выдаёт ошибку).

Быть может, есть аналоги *VideoView*, которые справятся с данным форматом?

Comment: Как насчет использования промежуточного узла, который будет, используя nginx и ffmpeg  генерировать HLS-поток (который кушают мэйнстримные браузыеры)?. Это более стабильный вариант (при нестабильном соединении), хоть и с отставанием секунд 10.

Answer (score 1):

https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample/src
пример того, как можно воспроизводить RTSP трансляцию на android. Использовал в своем проекте. Необходимо задать адрес трансляции в классе VideoActivity.java

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample);

    // здесь задается адрес трансляции
    mFilePath = rtsp://192.168.1.21:8557........

    Log.d(TAG, "Playing back " + mFilePath);

    mSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = mSurface.getHolder();
    //holder.addCallback(this);
}
```

Comment: Ссылки имеют свойство умирать, и если что-то при имплементации пойдёт не так, спросить там сложнее. Может быть, приведёте сами пример?

Answer (score 0):

[Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle) - классы и методы такие же как в sdk, есть примеры.